# Add image size option

Tags: wordpress

In my theme's functions.php I've added this:

```
function imagething () {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'new-custom-size', 1000, 500 );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'imagething' );
```

However, when I go to media, and upload a file, I can't select the new image format.

Comment: When you are on a post type (page, post, cpt) , and then add Media, you can select the "new-custom-size" from the sizes available, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

For make the the size created with [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) available in the media uploader select, you need to use the filter [image_size_names_choose](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_size_names_choose/) and add your custom created size to the list of available dimensions, like this:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'so46754923_image_size_names_choose' );

function so46754923_image_size_names_choose( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'new-custom-size' => __( 'New Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

---

### Image size not showing right in the image uploader select

In case the size you chose isn't showing right in the Image Uploader Select, it may be for 2 reasons:

1. [Content_Width](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) set for your theme
2. add_image_size() crop parameter is set to false, in this case, the uploaded image may not be in the desired size.

Content width defines width for your content (images, oembed, etc...)

Example: Suppose you are using twenty seventeen theme and added a image size like you said

```
add_image_size( 'new-custom-size', 1000, 500, true ); //in my example I've used crop true, so the image can really be 1000 x 500, in case you don't understand about crop you have to make a research about it.
```

In the Twenty Seventeen the content_width is set  for 525

```
$GLOBALS['content_width'] = 525;
```

And the you added the code I provided above ( so46754923_image_size_names_choose() )

You will see New Custom Size - 525 x 263
If you comment the line

```
$GLOBALS['content_width'] = 525;
```

You will see New Custom Size - 1000 x 500

Comment: Now it shows up but it says: 'New custom size name (640 x 480)', while I set the size to 1000 x 500.. ?

Comment: It's probably because you have [Content_Width](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) set in somewhere, probably in your functions php in your "after_setup_theme". With that variable set wordpress, don't show the right image dimensions but it brings the file you choose, but with the dimension hardcoded in the html for the value of the content with defined. read more in the Content Width link above.